# Port Forwarding- Multiple Routers (a TP-Link TLWR480N and an optronix modem)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, dsl-modem

Ok so I want to forward port 14492 on my computer (it has a static IP).
But the problem is that I have basically 2 routers, so my connection is like the following:-

Internet-->Router 1 (Optronix Modem)--> Router 2 (TL-WR840N)--> Computer

Now the problem is when I go into the settings of the 2nd router, by entering the default gateway (*192.168.0.1*), I saw that LAN subnet is **255.255.255.0** and WAN is **255.255.255.128**

***For Router 2:-***

WAN IP is of the form 10.x.x.x, and LAN is 192.168.0.1 (this is the link that I use to access its web UI).

How go I go about port forwarding? I'm a beginner so a little bit of explaining would be appreciated please. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a situation for a beginner. You are going down a long dark path. It would be easier to plug in to Router 1 for all internet facing servers. Use router 2 for LAN-only systems.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to understand double NAT:
http://www.practicallynetworked.com/networking/fixing_double_nat.htm

Then if you decide that you don't want to turn one of the devices in to a bridge then you would:

> on the first NAT device (the one closest to your Internet connection)
>   forward the port(s) you need to the IP address of your second router's WAN
>   port. Then on your router, forward the same port(s) to the address of
>   the device you need to reach.

Basically you will need to do everything twice and you're going to hate it. I suggest just putting router 2 in bridge mode.

EDIT: To do that, just plug all connections in to switch ports, avoiding the WAN port. Turn off DHCP. Make sure all devices are in the same subnet.

Comment: Can you clarify where that bridge option would be in the router options?

Comment: I added instructions for the TL-WR840N. I can't help you with the Optronix modem because I would need to read the manual. If you can find the full model number or manual you should be able to find more information.